# How to change class of table row below clicked one?

Tags: jquery, css, angular

I have an issue with toggling table row class.

I have the following tbody:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="click-row">
        <buttton>Show/Hide</button>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row"></tr>
    <tr class="click-row">
        <buttton>Show/Hide</button>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row"></tr>
    <tr class="click-row">
        <buttton>Show/Hide</button>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row"></tr>
    <tr class="click-row">
        <buttton>Show/Hide</button>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row"></tr>
</tbody>
```

And I am wondering, how I can toggle the first hidden row after the row with `hidden-row` has been clicked? I use Angular2.

In other words:

What I want to do, is to toggle the row that is 2 rows below tr, in which button was clicked.

Comment: your question is so confusing

Comment: Haha. What I want to do, is to toggle the row that is 2 rows below tr, in which button was clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would leverage `ngClass` to do that with an object for lines:

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="click-row">
    <buttton (click)="hiddenRows['0']=true">Show/Hide</button>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr class="hidden-row" ngClass="{'hidden-row': hiddenRows['0']}></tr>
  (...)
</tbody>
```

`hiddenRows` must be initialized within the constructor of the component.

Answer (score 1):

> Jquery Solution

using `.nextAll()` and `:first`

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('.hidden-row:first').toggle();
});
```

```css
.hidden-row {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="click-row">
      <td>
        <button>Show/Hide</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>1st hidden row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="click-row">
      <td>
        <button>Show/Hide</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>2nd hidden row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="click-row">
      <td>
        <button>Show/Hide</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>3rd hidden row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="click-row">
      <td>
        <button>Show/Hide</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>4th hidden row</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```